# Avoid app from closing on app switching

Tags: codenameone

Is it possible to prevent my app from closing. I have a performance problem on some Android devices whenever the app is switched from or the phone screen goes off. One solution I came up with is to keep the app open in the background.

How may I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: This is related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35510832/app-freezing-after-several-restarts

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you expect to have control over background execution of apps. There is no multi-tasking on mobile OS's despite vendor claims to the contrary.

If you have an app running in the background in iOS/Android taking up battery (network is battery intensive) it will be killed. Both OS's have options for specifically tailored background operations with quite a few stipulations involved and neither one is trivial. These are discussed in the [developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html).